# Can IE 9 still sign with Javascript like in old IE and Netscape / Firefox?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, certificate

It was possible to sign with digital certificate in IE and Netscape
http://bozhobg.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/how-to-create-a-digital-signing-solution-with-only-javascript/

What's the equivalent in IE 9 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have a problem with this.

The clue is in the code in the link you provided. Specifically, where it uses `new ActiveXObject()`.

ActiveX is a *very* old technology and it has severe security issues. For this reason, it's use has been discouraged for some time (this was the case a long time before the article you linked to was written).

IE9 does still support it, but only for legacy reasons; its use is strongly discouraged, and you will need to go to the browser config and disable some security settings in order to get it working.

If you do get activeX working in IE9, you'll also need to make sure you have the relevant activeX controls installed on your PC that actually do the work (I've not used the ones in question, so I can't advise on them). In addition, since the activeX technology is deprecated, you may find that the activeX control you need to use may not have been kept up-to-date. This may affect whether it works with newer versions of IE or Windows.

Comment: OK if activex is deprecated but then Microsoft replaced it by what ?

Comment: @user310291: I don't know an exact answer. Many of the common uses for activeX have direct equivalents in modern browsers, but that's not the case for you here. This sort of thing with proprietary activeX controls being integral to a site (particularly corporate intranets) is the biggest reason why IE6 kept such a strong market share for so long because it was impossible to upgrade. Given the very specific nature of the application in question, I would say you'd need a custom-written browser plug-in, but that would need it to have been written by the authors of the original activex control.